# Analysis Services Cube hierarchy total

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I cannot understand how hierarchy works in cubes. I have AdventureWork 2014 database example and I'm using MDX to query it. For example I want to get values of orders of each product in Australia country. My results:

[image]

If calculate manually, to sum of orders: 1713, what has big difference with total in the cube:

[image]

[image]

Does anybody know how this works?

Comment: You should be posting your queries so that the one answering can easily use them. They cannot be copied from image.

Comment: Based on quick investigation, the issue is with the dimension setting most probably. If you want to understand hierarchies use "InternetSales" as measure instead of this which is distinctCount in nature